# Azure IoTHub Diagnostic Settings not logging "Device Telemetry"

Tags: azure-iot-hub

We have an Azure IoTHub instance and turned on the "Diagnostic Settings" with everything enabled. Additionally, all diagnostics should be archived into a Blob Storage. This works well for `cd2twinoperations`, `d2ctwinoperations`, `fileuploadoperations` and a few others, however, not for `Device Telemetry`. We have enabled this setting (see image):
[image: Device Telemetry diagnostic settings]

---

I can see in the "Metrics" that telemetry messages where sent.
Why are no logs created for the `Device Telemetry` category?

[image: telemetry messages metrics]

**Edit:**
Maybe it makes sense to also explain *why* we would need this. The usecase is to find the amount of telemetry messages sent per device. For fileupload operations we can just execute a query on the `Analytics workspace` and find the number of operations. We could implement a custom solution (by subscribing to the `Device Telemetry` messages and "count it by hand") but of course this is much more work than just querying the log analytics.

Comment: able to Add [Diagnostic setting](https://i.imgur.com/cjmsVIO.png) get the [log](https://i.imgur.com/KQrYMfZ.png) in [AzureDiagnostics](https://i.imgur.com/KLUHsSY.png) .

Comment: sample [Metric](https://i.imgur.com/HjRVt2y.png) with Diagnostic setting for above

Comment: I do get a metric for this kind of diagnostics, but I want to query it from the `Log Analytics` workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/monitor-iot-hub-reference#device-telemetry): "The device telemetry category tracks errors that occur at the IoT hub and are related to the telemetry pipeline. This category includes errors that occur when sending telemetry events (such as throttling) and receiving telemetry events (such as unauthorized reader)."

Unless there are errors, you wouldn't expect to see any telemetry diagnostics.

If you want to capture the telemetry the device is sending in a storage account, you need to set up a route to your storage account. See [Send device data to Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-routing) to get started.

Edit following your comment about your usecase:
I'm able to see metrics such as `d2c.telemetry.ingress.success` and `devices.totalDevices` in the exported metrics as follows:

1. Make sure on the **Diagnostic setting** page for your hub that you select the **AllMetrics** option at the bottom of the page.
2. In your blob storage account (if that's where your exporting to), look in the container called **insights-logs-pt1m**.
3. If you're using a log analytics workspace you can query the **AzureMetrics** table in **Logs**:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, I have read this, but I was a bit confused as the same is written for the `FileUploadOperations`: `The file upload category tracks errors that occur at the IoT hub and are related to file upload functionality. [...]`. And for those operations we _do_ get logs when they occured.

Comment: Again thanks for the update. I checked the logs and indeed we have those in the blob storage, unfortunately, they only show the amount of telemetry received but do not extend it with properties (in this case we would need a deviceId to identify how many telemetry messages each device sent). 
Since I did not specifically ask for this I will accept your answer as you answered my initial question